# Why is my bash "history" command 56x slower in a subshell?

Tags: bash, performance, history, subshell

Why does running the bash `history` builtin function in a subshell run 56x slower?

(I have 22k lines in my history.  Maybe that is significant?)

```bash
$ time history > /dev/null

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.049s
sys     0m0.015s

$ # in a subshell it runs 56x slower:
$ time (history > /dev/null)

real    0m4.780s
user    0m2.558s
sys     0m2.215s

$ # trying "date" instead to show "time" isn't the issue:

$ date; history > /dev/null; date
Wed Oct 21 21:50:51 PDT 2020
Wed Oct 21 21:50:51 PDT 2020  (< 1 sec)

$ date; (history > /dev/null); date
Wed Oct 21 21:50:51 PDT 2020
Wed Oct 21 21:50:56 PDT 2020  (5 secs)

$ # each command in a pipeline is executed in a subshell (bash(1))
$ date; history | tail -1 > /dev/null; date
Wed Oct 21 21:50:56 PDT 2020
Wed Oct 21 21:51:01 PDT 2020  (5 secs)

$ history|wc -l
   22267

$ # time for a simple command ("date")
$ time date
Sat Jul  2 17:40:33 PDT 2022

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
```

**Mac OS version:** macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Mystery.  It's not slower for me.  (But I have a limit of 2000 lines.)

Comment: Interesting but i can't reproduse on `Linux Mint 20`, `bash 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`  test: 
time history > /dev/null

real 0m0,001s
user 0m0,001s
sys 0m0,000s

time (history > /dev/null)

real 0m0,001s
user 0m0,001s
sys 0m0,000s

Comment: I have 22k lines of history.  Maybe that is a deciding factor.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @RobBednark : Can't reproduce on Cygwin.

Comment: Can't reproduce with 1670-line ~/.bash_history. Bash 5.0.17(1)-release on Ubuntu 20.04. But this only shows one run. If you had consistent behaviour over *many* interleaved executions that might be more telling. Also, part of the runtime (maybe a huge part) is from starting the subshell. Have you tried with a no-op command like `true`?